# What do you call a class that can be disabled

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, terminology, multithreading

Is there a design pattern that fits this description? A factory that creates classes that can be disabled and enabled. The users of the class don't know if the functionality is enabled or disabled--they just call methods on the class. What are appropriate names for this kind of factory and class? 
How do you make this pseudocode correct and thread-safe?

```
class FooFactory {
    static enabled;
    List foos = new ArrayList();
    getFoo() {
        Foo foo = new EnabledOrDisabledFoo(enabled);
        foos.add(foo);
        return foo;
    }
    setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        for (Foo foo : foos)
            foo.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}

class EnabledOrDisabledFoo implements Foo {
    private enabled;
    private Foo;
    EnabledOrDisabledFoo(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    doFoo() {
        if (enabled)
            foo.doFoo();
    }
}

class FooConsumer {
    Foo foo = FooFactory.getFoo();
    foo.doFoo();
}

class FooManager {
    FooFactory.setEnabled(true);
    FooFactory.setEnabled(false);
    FooFactory.setEnabled(true);
    FooFactory.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify the question. You need some components to be capable of being set as enabled or disabled, but avoiding consumers to be aware of this capability. Am I right?

Comment: can you please confirm or clarify: 1) it’s not classes that are disabled but parts of their methods ? 2) if the choice between enabled or disabled depends on the factory configuration (i.e. all the classes generated are either enabled or disabled) or if the factory needs to chose every time it has to create an object ? 3) once created, can an object be enabled/disabled dynamically later on ?

Comment: It looks like you merged the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) with another implementation. I'd argue that you could better split responsibility by having two implementations of `Foo`: `DefaultFoo` (whatever the real name is) and `NullObjectFoo`, and then the factory is responsible for instantiating the correct implementation based on the `enabled` variable. However, this does mean that if you need to toggle the state on the fly on an existing instance, you might need a different strategy to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe would only be feasible for *void* methods, getting something would need to return some default.

To do that *dynamically,* one would use **delegation** and depending on a flag enable/disable the passing.

There is a related technique: the **lookup/discovery** of capabilities.

Instead of having a class FlyingAnimal, have a class Animal with a dynamic lookup of Flying.

I would consider testing capabilities/features:

```
interface Flying { void fly(); }
interface Swimming { void swim(); }

Animal animal = ...

Optional<Flying> flying = animal.lookup(Flying.class);
flying.ifPresent(f -> f.fly());    interface Flying { void fly(); }

Optional<Swimming> swimming = animal.lookup(Swimming.class);
swimming.ifPresent(sw -> sw.swim());
```

Animal need not implement any interface, but you can look up (`lookup` or maybe `as`) capabilities. This is extendible in the future, dynamic: can change at run-time.

Implementation as

```
private Map<Class<?>, ?> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T> Optional<T> lookup(Class<T> type) {
     Object instance = map.get(type);
     if (instance == null) {
         return Optional.empty();
     }
     return Optional.of(type.cast(instance));
}

<S> void register(Class<S> type, S instance) {
    map.put(type, instance);
}
```

The implementation does a safe dynamic cast, as register ensures the safe filling of (key, value) entries.

The advantage of a **lookup** mechanism (with `Optional`) is that its usage is optimally guarded.

On pattern naming: the original notion probably best is named **delegation with a switch to a dummy/null**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a name for this specifically.  It seems like a simplified form of the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but you could also maybe describe this as using the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or a combination of the two.

The simplest thing to make this thread safe would be to do this:

```
class EnabledOrDisabledFoo implements Foo {
    private final AtomicBoolean enabled = new AtomicBoolean();
    private Foo;
    EnabledOrDisabledFoo(boolean enabled) {
        setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.set(enabled);
    }
    doFoo() {
        if (enabled.get())
            foo.doFoo();
    }
}
```

This will simply make sure that once set is called, all threads that subsequently read the value will see that value.  If you have more complex threading coordination requirements, this may not suffice.